# Show $f(x)=|x|^{p}$ is continous for all $p \geq 1, p \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, continuity

I'm trying to show this using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. I get stuck right at $| \ |x|^{p}-|y|^{p}|$. I have tried the inequality $|a+b|^{p} \leq 2^{p-1}(|a|^{p}+|b|^{p})$. I tried doing a composition of $h(x)=|x|$ and $g(x)=x^{p}$, but I couldn't show $g$ is continuous. I also thought about being able to show open images map back to open pre-images since this method may not be feasible. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Why make life hard? It's just a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: Are you referring to $h$ and $g$ here or others? How do we show those are continuous?

Comment: Yes I refer to $h$ and $g$. It depends on your definition, but for real $p$ the definition $x^p := \exp(p \log(x))$ for $x > 0$ is common, so it is just a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: If $x = 0$, then $\bigl||x|^{p} - |y|^{p}\bigr| = |y|^{p} = |y|\, |y|^{1-p}$, so it suffices to show $|y|^{1-p}$ is bounded near $0$. Otherwise, write $\bigl||x|^{p} - |y|^{p}\bigr| = |x|^{p} \bigl|1 - |\frac{y}{x}|^{p}\bigr|$, which reduces you to showing continuity at $1$. Still, further progress is going to come down to your definition of exponentiation.

Comment: @Andrew Could you please clarify your statements for me? For bounded near 0, why do you split off a $1-p$ and why isn't it $p-1$? For cont. at 1, we still have an $x$ term in front and how do we handle the $y/x$? I honestly don't know about different definitions of exponentiation. Thank you.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek Thanks. With Andrew's tip for when $x=0$, I believe that should do it, assuming that $|x^{p}| = |x|^{p}$ in the composition, which I believe is true but haven't proven rigorously.

Comment: @LP: Whoops...typo on my part. For your second question, if $x \neq 0$ is fixed and $y \to x$, then $y/x \to 1$. The $|x|^{p}$ term is bounded, so it's enough to show the other factor goes to $0$.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you very much!